# Ionic Visual Studio Cordova iOS remotebuild ETIMEDOUT

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

Trying to get up and running with Ionic on my Windows PC + Mac setup. I ran through the [iOS remotebuild setup guide](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) last night and was actually able to get the side menu template app to build and run on the iOS simulator on my mac. This morning I tried again and am constantly getting:

```
Error: An error occurred uploading to the build server https://mymac.local:3000/cordova: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Through searching it seems that everyone who ran into a similar issue was due to proxy settings but I am not using a proxy and it worked last night without any additional configuration.

Things I have tried:

- New certificates with remotebuild certificates generate

Every certificate I always see on the mac terminal:

```
GET /certs/xxxxxx 200 xx.xxx ms - 4250
GET /modules/taco-remote 200 xx.xxx ms -7
```

so that doesn't seem to be an issue

- Restarting the remotebuild server
- Using a different port on the remotebuild server
- Restarting my Mac
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Restarting my Windows PC
- Starting a new Ionic project
- Non-secure (http) mode

I can navigate to http://mymac.local:3000 in a browser and I see:

```
Remote build Express server open for business on port 3000
```

I also ran through the [troubleshooting guide](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#errors) but nothing matched what I was experiencing which is why I am posting here.

Answer (score 0):

you need check the mac Ip address from network preferences and set this IP address to the visual studio -> tools -> options -> tools for Apache Cordova -> ios configuration.